# Re-naming our chat room.

Tags: discussion, chat

Most other sites have chat rooms with unique names that are related to the site's topic, but don't just duplicate the site's name.  Here's some examples:

- SuperUser:  Root Access
- ServerFault:  The Comms Room
- RPG:  The Game Table
- Apple:  Ask Different
- Gaming:  The Bridge
- Cooking:  The Frying Pan
- WordPress:  StopPress

Does anyone have ideas for what we could re-name ours to?

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/it-security

Comment: FWIW, the *moderator* chat room for money.SE uses the name **The Vault**, so you security guys come up with something else, mkay? I've suggested one below :-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea - Thanks for the heads-up.  Love your suggestion!

Comment: So - once we are officially out of beta, shall we take a poll on the top 4 to decide the final name, or shall we just hammer it out in chat:-)

Comment: As announced in the banner on all security.stackexchange.com pages, "If you want to vote on the new Security Chat room name, come on into chat before 22:00 UTC 21 April and leave your vote for one of: DMZ, Crypt, SOC or Firewall".

Answer (score 17):

The DMZ.

Comment: Declared "the winner" in the chat vote 2011-04-21!

Answer (score 6):

Keeping it simple, and following in the same lines as Comms Room.

Security Operations Center -- SOC

Answer (score 6):

The Firewall

That also enables facebook-like comments such as "write on your (fire)wall"...

Answer (score 6):

Here's a new one....

> The Crypt

<sub>pretty much the way security guys are seen in many orgs anyway....</sub>

Comment: Fasten your drool cups, and ready your vomit bags! We're going to the movies! Frights, camera, action! [cackles]

Comment: Really liking the Crypt!

Comment: So glad you could drop in, kill-seekers! Don't worry about me, it only *hearse* when I laugh!

Comment: @packs hmm, if there is ever an SE for medical examiners, or undertakers, they'd probably want this name back....

Comment: Of course, it may also be considered stepping on toes for these guys http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography

Comment: @Avid The medical examiners can have The Morgue, that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

And yet another one that occured to me...

> Full Disclosure

Comment: I like it!&nbsp

Answer (score 3):

Home of Bobby Tables

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw this in, just because it pooped into my head.  As the "anti-DMZ" (which I'd expect would be more correct for us), how about...

```
Air-Gapped
```

Answer (score 2):

The Exploit

Answer (score 2):

Or, "ITsec", spelling concordant with "[IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec)"

Answer (score 2):

And more on the theme

> Redacted

Answer (score 2):

Following up @Richard - we could have

- The Bastion
- The Tower
- The Keep
- The Dungeon (or is that for Bondage.stackexchange.com)

along with @AviD's the Crypt, that gives us some good castle-ing

Answer (score 1):

Adding another one...

> Under the Bridge

cuz thats where us security trolls usually live...

Comment: Very Red Hot Chili Peppers!

Answer (score 1):

```
Bastion Host
```

We need more castle-building metaphors.

Answer (score 0):

Blatantly stolen from a sysadmin suggestion for a different room.

> Council of Unspeakables