# Can we rename the DMZ to "The Honeypot"?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I know it's a silly request, but I just feel like name would fit the theme of Information Security better. It was also inspired by [this rather funny question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140872/how-can-one-find-the-honeypot), where somebody wanted to create a honeypot to watch other hackers.

Would people like to see this change?

Comment: Furthermore, "DMZ" makes no sense. The architecture is all wrong.

Comment: The name was originally discussed in [Re-naming our chat room.](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209/129883) Looks like "Honeypot" was not suggested at the time.

Comment: @FireQuacker But it's such a good name

Answer (score 3):

I think DMZ is more appropriate; it donotes a place between the wide open internet and the protected internal network. Honeypot denotes a attractive target that appears to have value but is a decoy to distract attackers from the targets of real value.

Comment: But the DMZ doesn't sit between anything. And instead, the Honeypot is something that attracts hackers

Comment: The chat room can _very_ _much_ distract people from things of more value, be it answering questions on the main site, or doing actual work... :D